# AWS Kinesis - data source on a third party server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

New to AWS Kinesis.

We're trying to evaluate whether it makes sense or even possible to place events captured in a log file which is located on a third party server into AWS Kinesis stream, given that we only have a VPN access to this server where the log file is.

Based on going through AWS docs, I'm assuming that short of our client giving us access to run some implementation of a Kinesis "Producer" application on that server where these events can be continuously read from the said log file and then sending them to AWS Kinesis stream there no other feasible options.

Is this assumption correct, has anyone had to deal with anything similar to this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have access to the log file, you could in theory push to kinesis from other machines.
the implementation of that might be a bit funny and yes, ideally you would be able to run the kinesis producer on the machine that has the logs